# How to make Ctrl-Up/Down scroll a single line in Visual Studio 2015 community

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

It's driving me nuts that Ctrl-Up/Down jumps the cursor to the start of the next or previous function definition in Visual Studio 2015 Community.

Previously I've had it so that Ctrl-Up/Down scrolls the window a single line without moving the cursor.

I've tried setting the shortcut for Edit.ScrollLineUp under :
Tools --> Options --> Environment --> Keyboard --> Edit.ScrollLineUp

But it still jumps to functions rather than scrolling.

What am I missing !?!?!

TIA

Comment: did you edit also on the section of text editor?

Comment: as far as i can remember there's a combobox in the Tools -> Options -> Environment, select first text editor then change the shortcut key you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I got what you need,
Go to Tools -> Options -> Keyboard

> Show commands containing: type edit.scrolllineup
>
> Shortcuts for selected command: Ctrl + Up Arrow(Text Editor)

Then just press button **Remove**

Comment: Borlagdan answers don't work -- too vague.  But after trial-and-error for 1/2 hour, my answer below (a superset to Bor's) works.

Answer (score -1):

First off, yes, Tools >> Options >> Env.. >> Keyboard
is an insane user interface.  You will feel like Alice in Wonderline.

But you will get scroll up/down working!

Here's what works, as of Nov 2021...

STEP 1. REMOVE THE PREVIOUS STUPID DEFAULT...
tools >> options >> env.. >> keyboard
Apply.. >> (Default)
Show.. >> edit.scrollline.. >> select Edit.Scroll.LineDown >> Remove >> OK
...repeat for UP.

STEP 2. RESTORE THE PREVIOUS PREVIOUS SMART DEFAULT...
tools >> options >> env.. >> keyboard
Press shortcut keys >> ctrl-down/up >> Assign >> OK >> boom!

"one side will make you grow SHOW-tah;
the other side will make you grow TOLL-ah."
-- the caterpillar